# how to log out from microsoft outlook 2007?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007, logout

I cannot figure out how to log out from (email) Outlook 2007. I have searched web to get the answer of this simple question but I am failed to get correct solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [set a password for your Personal Folders (.PST) file](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/set-a-password-to-help-protect-your-outlook-information-HA010149561.aspx) as follows:

1. On the **File** menu, click **Data File Management** to open the Account Settings dialog box.
2. On the **Data Files** tab, click the Personal Folders file (.PST) for which you want to create a password, and then click **Settings** to open the Personal Folders dialog box.
3. Click the **Change password** button.

   Note: This button does not appear if your e-mail account runs on Microsoft Exchange. Your Outlook folders are already protected by your Exchange password.
4. In the **New password** box, type your new password. The password can be up to 15 characters long and case-sensitive.
5. In the **Verify password** box, type your new password again.
6. If you share a computer with others, don't select the **Save this password in your password list** check box. Anyone with access to the computer could potentially open your .PST file.

   If your Windows user account is password protected, and no other user has access to the computer, you can select the **Save this password in your password list** check box if you want to avoid entering your password each time you need to use the .PST file.
7. Click **OK** twice, and then click **Close**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the purpose of having a Desktop mail box application, is you always want to have
the emails offline, so logout concept contradicts with (you use logout usually on web
sites)

if you want that every time outlook requires a password, then check options
in Outlook 2007 related to user account

Answer (score 0):

There is only work offline mode as no logout option is there. Try adding a new email account in email configuration. Hope then you will be able to access the other account as on starting outlook it might prompt for the choice as to open which email account and would ask for password.